# In Mac terminal, why does this code give me "command not found", "syntax error near unexpected token", and " 'then'?

Tags: terminal

```
read command;

if[ $command = "make"]
then
    echo "Hello"
elif[ $command = "make run"]
then 
    echo "Goodbye"
fi
```

I have looked at similar questions and their solutions are not helping here.

Comment: You need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Comment: on the inside or outside? ex(if [$command = "make" ]) or (if[ $command = "make" ])

Comment: Both inside and outside, check the code below, I already modified it, you can see the spaces I added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to respect spaces in bash scripts like @Jonny Henly said. Here is a modified version of your code, try it and see if it works.

```
read command;

if [ $command = "make" ]
then
    echo "Hello"
elif [ $command = "make run" ]
then 
    echo "Goodbye"
fi
```

Hope it helps.